# Https connect to http?

Tags: python, django, reactjs

our front-end is react.js run with https 443 port
backend is django  run with http 80 port

The front-end will call django api
But it seems https can't communiate with http

I don't some question :

What should I setting ??
I should set on front-end or backend??

By the way, we use 2 port is because we still have no idea how to intergrate django and reactjs
If you know how to do this,please guide me

Comment: How it could be that you use react as http server?

Answer (score 0):

Best bet might be to use NGINX or something similar and host both via HTTPS. My guess for what is happening, even thought you are much to vague, is the HTTPS client is complaining, or refusing, to use an unsecure connection to your backend server. This is because once there is a single insecure connection the potential for a security hole arises. If you use NGINX then both could be hosted on port 443 using an SSL cert with the client being the root and the backend being located at something like www.your.domain/api or something like api.your.domain (this is the method I use most of the time). Though with it being a subdomain you do potentially need another SSL cert unless you have a wildcard cert.

Best bet though is to give more info and I can see about updating this answer at that time.

Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04